# Sql - Rolling up multiple rows to one row

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a dataset as follows;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxXqh.png)

I need to display the data on row per customer as follows;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH9g4.png)

I'm not proficient at all at sql so any help would be greatly appreciated.

AD

Comment: What's the expected result if a customer has 3 (or 8) accounts?

Comment: Thats a good question. If a Customer had >2 accounts, I would like to display all accounts held across one row please.

Comment: I would say that a Customer would have no more than 10 accounts.

Comment: Do you want a query that returns 10 account columns, and 10 scode columns?

Comment: Yes, correct, this is what I would lke to see (including all other fields within the existing table (additional customer details, etc).

Comment: Please show your sample data and desired results as text in your post, not images or links.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Assign a ROW_NUMBER to the accounts and then PIVOT using those row_numbers

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem can be solved by unpivoting the data.
The UNPIVOT in sql can help but for that need certain info to identify the constraints,
How many accounts does one customer can have,
If a customer has 2 acct and other has 3 acct so what should be populated for acct 3 column for first customer